# How do i fix this error. Iam starting my first django project

Tags: django-templates

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/playgroung/hello
Using the URLconf defined in storefront.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, playgroung/hello, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Iam trying to display webpage hello world

Comment: Show us the urls.py files in app and project.